# How to obtain date and time from JPEG in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, jpeg, archive

I have many thousands of digital pictures taken over the past 15 years. Unfortunately, there is some problems with my archive of them:

- Folders contain duplicates of the same photo, but possibly with a different name.
- Some cameras reset the numbering, e.g. IMG_9999.jpg back to zero, so if I just copy them all into a directory as named, there are naming conflicts.
- I had multiple cameras, so some files have the same name, but are different subjects.
- All are JPEG, although they come from five different cameras, over a span of many years, so the format of JPEG might have some difference.

My solution is to copy all of the images from the multiple archive folders into a single output folder, naming them by descending the date and time, with that data extracted from the file, plus the sha1sum of the file:

```
2012-04-01_16:34_87514f3c2734f963891089cef0bb547f5d36451f.jpg
```

In this way, duplicates are removed and multiple copies of the same photo cannot exist.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.jpg
do
    date=`echo "2019-08-10"`
    checksum=`sha1sum $i | awk -F" " '{ print $1}'`
    cp $i OUT/$date\_$checksum\.jpg
    echo "Copied "$i" to OUT/"$date\_$checksum\.jpg"."
done
```

I created this script above, which manages to copy the file to another folder, by sha1sum. How can I accurately obtain the date and time the photo was taken, so that data can be added to the filename as well?

Comment: Exiftool might help.  `sudo apt install exiftool` (or yum, etc.)

Comment: (1) Always preserve the original set of files in their directories untouched. (2) Keep a backup of the original set that is never touched. (3) The Linux tools `jhead` and `exiftool` are usable for what you need. (4) using a database to store the location of the images (as well as whatever other information about each photo you want) makes the directories they are stored in irrelevant.

Comment: And in addition, symlinks might come in handy.

Comment: If you have not heard of the Gallery2 photo database system, it is worth its weight in gold for photo management. It has also been forked and updated for php7 on github [Gallery2-php7](https://github.com/gregstoll/gallery2) and [Gallery2-Second Fork](https://github.com/pbobbenb/gallery2). You can simply keep your existing directory structure and it will assemble all photos based on the date for you with all data kept in MySQL (MariaDB) tables. It provides a web-interface (with several levels of password protection). I have used it for a decade.

Comment: In direct answer to your question, using `jhead` (much faster than `exiftool`), you would use, e.g. `jhead tmp/IMG_0704.JPG | sed -n 's/File\ date[^:]*:[ ]//p'` and would obtain `2011:09:17 13:39:54` which can then be passed to `date -d` to obtain any date format you like.